# Moving from Qt 4.x (Ubuntu Linux) to Qt 5.1 (Windows 7)

Tags: c++, linux, windows, qt, qt-creator

I made a program by using Qt Creator in Qt 4.x on an Ubuntu Linux platform in the last year. Now I don't use linux, instead I use Windows 7. I once again need my program which I made last year. I downloaded and installed Qt Creator onto Windows 7 platform. It came with Qt 5.1. I try to rebuilt it. I got below messages. What should I do?

C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QtGui/QApplication': No such file or directory
C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QDialog': No such file or directory

Thanks

Comment: `<QtGui/QApplication>` is now just `<QApplication>`.

Answer (score 2):

In Qt5 *QApplication* is no longer part of **QtGui** module, it's now in **QtWidgets**. In your `#include` directive use `<QtWidgets/QApplication>`, the same applies to *QDialog*.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your `.pro` file.

```
QT += ...
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
```

The Qt modules have been [rearranged](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/qt5-intro.html#modularized-qt-libraries) somewhat in Qt5.  Also this will teach for leaving Linux!

Comment: I added like this

`QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = MVMO_01`

it still gives the same errors. May it be related to "INCLUDEPATH" or "DEPENDPATH"?

Comment: You don't need the `INCLUDEPATH` for Qt's own stuff, as Qt should know where they are already.  In Qt Creator you can view the Qt Versions available and see where it thinks the headers are (under `QT_INSTALL_HEADERS`).

Comment: Where is the QT_INSTALL_HEADERS tag?

Comment: Go to Tools->Options, then Build & Run->Qt Versions tab.  Click on your Qt version and expand it's details.

Comment: You should _run qmake_ after you modify the .pro file and only after that try to build your application.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good guide on what has changed from QT 4.x to 5.x http://qt-project.org/wiki/Transition_from_Qt_4.x_to_Qt5